# Python 3.63, Vigenere cypher prints more than the range

Tags: python-3.x, range, newline, vigenere

first question! I tried searching around for answers before asking, but I couldn't find any other than completely other code... :\ 
 my code is as follows:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("usage: python vigenere.py key")
    exit(1)

key = (sys.argv[1])
s = input("plaintext: ")
j = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    # so that j wraps around
    j = j % len(key)
    for j in range(len(key)):
        # check for every j in key if it is upper, or lowercase
        if ord(key[j]) >= ord("A") and ord(key[j]) <= ord("Z"):
            j -= 65
        elif ord(key[j]) >= ord("a") and ord(key[j]) <= ord("z"):
            j -= 97
        # for every capital letter, print out the encyphered letter
        if ord(s[i]) >= ord("A") and ord(s[i]) <= ord("Z"):
            print("1{}".format(chr((ord(s[i]) + j - 65) % 26 + 65), end=''))

        # same for every non capital
        elif ord(s[i]) >= ord("a") and ord(s[i]) <= ord("z"):
            print("2{}".format(chr((ord(s[i]) + j - 97) % 26 + 97), end=''))

        # if it is not capital, print it out
        else:
            print("3{}".format(s[i]), end='')
```

It is a vigenere cypher, it should take a key, and a plaintext and encypher the plaintext with the key. When I run:

```
>python vigenere.py abc

plaintext: abc

I get:

2h

2i

2j

2i

2j

2k

2j

2k

2l
```

(I put the 1, 2 and 3 in there so I can see if the capital and non capital works.)

So my question is, where do the newlines come from? I put =end'' after every print.
Also, I can't see how it prints over the range. I tried finding solutions, but those include code not at all similar to mine. Anyone got tips for my problems,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move parenthesis, in your code `end=''` is for `format` function :

```
print("1{}".format(chr((ord(s[i]) + j - 65) % 26 + 65), end=''))
```

to

```
print("1{}".format(chr((ord(s[i]) + j - 65) % 26 + 65)), end='')
```

and dedent after the second `for` http://rextester.com/VOVSP83705

```
import sys


key = "key"
s = "abc"

j = 0
for i in range(len(s)):    
    # so that j wraps around
    j = j % len(key)
    for j in range(len(key)):
        # check for every j in key if it is upper, or lowercase
        if ord(key[j]) >= ord("A") and ord(key[j]) <= ord("Z"):
            j -= 65
        elif ord(key[j]) >= ord("a") and ord(key[j]) <= ord("z"):
            j -= 97
    # for every capital letter, print out the encyphered letter
    if ord(s[i]) >= ord("A") and ord(s[i]) <= ord("Z"):
        print("{}".format(chr((ord(s[i]) + j - 65) % 26 + 65)), end='')            

    # same for every non capital
    elif ord(s[i]) >= ord("a") and ord(s[i]) <= ord("z"):
       print("{}".format(chr((ord(s[i]) + j - 97) % 26 + 97)), end='')

    # if it is not capital, print it out
    else:
        print("{}".format(s[i]), end='')
```